# enable autocomplete form from iframe to parent page

Tags: javascript, forms, iframe, form-submit

I have this test site http://itmjobs.ro/lidl/searching.php . I can search from parent to iframe, that's fine, but.. Iframe form has autocomplete feature which I would like to work on my parent page boxes too if possible. if you check 'Modify search' on iframe and try to search, after you enter second letter will autocomplete text. Is it possible to make it work on parent page too ?